# Alguns erros no Android

Tags: java, android

Eu estou tentando começar a programar no Android. Criei o projeto e veio esse código:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tela_1);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main1, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

porem com esses erros:

[image]

Como resolver ??

Comment: Quer dizer que a tela_1 Não está presente na apresentação do APK.

Comment: Mas o projeto foi criado assim, não modifiquei nada.

Comment: https://missaodeveloper.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/activity-do-android-e-o-metodo-oncreate/ [PT-BR]

Comment: O problema deve ser o import da classe R. Veja os imports na classe e primeiro remova o import da classe R, depois posiciona o cursor na variavel com o erro, pressione o atalho ALT+ENTER e importa ela novamente

Comment: Veja na pasta res > layout se existe um arquivo chamado tela_1.xml. Se não tiver é este o problema.

Comment: Primeiro de tudo sugiro que migre pro Android Studio, posto que o suporte ao Eclipse foi descontinuado e também o código gerado por ele é de uma versão descontinuada do SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Veja que a Herança de ActionBarActivity está depreciada isso por que quando criado um projeto android ele já tenta configurar a lib de appcompatv7 no seu projeto as vezes a ide buga.Verifique se no seu projeto foi importada a appcompatv7 e depois dê um Clean no projeto .

Se não foi importada automaticamente faça isso

```
   Eclipse -> Import -> Existing Android Code into workspace.
```

Procure pela pasta SDK

```
   sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat to your Eclipse workspace.
```

Depois de importar adicione a library no seu projeto

```
   Select Android -> Library -> Add.
```

Limpe o  projeto e tente novamente

Answer (score 0):

A resposta do @Jose Vieira Neto também é valida, mais acredito que o problema está em algum XML de layout ou mesmo de strings, dimensions ou algo parecido. Isso deve estar causando erro na geração do arquivo R.java que é o arquivo de intercambio entre os resources da aplicação e o código fonte.